Snowflake - error while executing stored procedure with for loops
I have the following stored procedure:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE db.schema.sp_1()
RETURNS DATE
LANGUAGE SQL 
AS
$$
DECLARE
    select_statement_stream VARCHAR;
    select_statement_status VARCHAR;
    r INTEGER;
    select_date DATE;
    stream_result RESULTSET;
    query_result RESULTSET;
BEGIN
    IF (SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('db.schema.stream_1') = true) THEN select_statement_stream := 'SELECT process_date::DATE AS process_date FROM db.schema.stream_1 GROUP BY process_date::DATE LIMIT 1'; -- This stream has data
    END IF;
    
    stream_result := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :select_statement_stream);

    LET c1 CURSOR FOR stream_result;
    FOR row_variable IN c1 DO
        select_date := to_date(row_variable.process_date);
        select_statement_status := 'SELECT stg.process_date::DATE AS process_date, stg.table_name, stg.flag FROM db.schema.status_loads stg WHERE ''' || :select_date || ''' = stg.process_date::DATE';
    query_result := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :select_statement_status);
        LET c2 CURSOR FOR query_result;
        FOR row_variable_2 IN c2 DO
            r := row_variable_2.flag; -- flag is an integer column
            insert into db.schema.test_table values (:r); -- Table db.schema.test_table has only 1 column 'id' declared as INTEGER
        END FOR inner_loop;
    END FOR outer_loop;
    RETURN (:select_date);
END;
$$;

After this I want to do SELECT * FROM db.schema.test_table and see all the 0 and 1 that the db.schema.status_loads table already had loaded in that flag column.
But when I called the stored procedure:
call db.schema.sp_1();

I get an error:

Expression type does not match column data type, expecting DATE but got NUMBER(38,0) for column process_date


Try casting the :select_date to ::DATE in where clause
